# Triggered Send API not sending emails

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud

I am trying to send an email via Triggered Send Object SOAP API. The API returns a success message "Created TriggeredSend" and everything appears to be OK as displayed in the reports (emails sent) but so far I haven't actually received any email. I tried different email addresses as receipients however none of the emails have been received (I checked the spam folders too). Can anyone tell what could be wrong? I am trying out the samples from the starter kit PHP APIstarterKit-V1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the question. Would you mind providing more code of what you are doing specifically - that will help us answer your question faster. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Here is the code that i used: http://pastebin.com/HtiECe5h
its straight from the starter kit sample code. Thanks

Comment: Also apart from above I created triggered send definition and started it before sending, but for some reason emails aren't received even though the interface and reports show emails as sent.

Comment: I see the creation part, but not seeing the actual sending of the trigger.  There are two parts - creation and sending. Do you have a sample of the sending portion?

Comment: Do you mean ExactTarget_TriggeredSend()? Its in the above code at line 24. If not, can you send me the link/sample to how send part is implemented?

Comment: Also wondering how without the send part it shows emails as emails sent? I noticed the that email was queued under the interaction tab and after a while it was in sent list. Thanks for your help

Comment: hi @Kelly J Andrews any insights on this? thanks

Comment: Hmm, seems like it's being sent - not exactly sure why it's not hitting your inbox. You may need to contact global support to see if there are any errors happening.

Comment: I see. The global support asked me to post question on stackexchange as they couldn't figure out the problem. I will try to investigate it more from my end. thanks !

Comment: Have you reviewed this section of the docs? - http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/

Comment: Also - if you could log your SOAP packets, that would also be helpful - I'll try to debug as much as I can with you, but if it hits the queue, and then is eventually sent, you should be doing everything correctly, I'm just not sure where the hold up is on the actual send.

Answer (score 1):

Hey a shot in the dark here.  If you are doing this in your sandbox, your org's Email Deliverability may be set to a restrictive setting: `No access`, or `System email only`.

To check this go to `Setup | Email Administration | Deliverability` and check the `Access level` drop-down-menu.

I have run into problems when testing code involving Apex's send email capability.  Unfortunately I am unsure how ExactTarget integrates with these settings.

*[See the docs on Configuring Deliverability Settings for more details [http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm]](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm%5d)*

Answer (score 0):

Getting the code right is only half the battle. My problem was I did not set up the UI correctly. You also need to create a TriggeredSendDefinition in the UI, link a subscriber list to it, link your email template to it (unless you are providing the content) and optionally a DataExtension too (if you are substituting values into a template). Key pieces of the API call are the CustomerKey in the TSD in the API call needs to match the ExternalKey of the TSD definition in the UI, and you need to provide a SubscriberKey (usually email address but not necessarily) in the Subscriber as that is the key used to insert/update your subscriber (in the API call) into the subscriber list linked to the TSD in the UI. Hope this helps! - gr